# What does this query do?

Tags: sql

I'm studying for the final exam and this comes up in a past exam:

> Table: Nurse - (**nid:int**, nname:string, age:real, salary:real,
>   sid:int)
>  Table: Supervisor - (**sid:int**, rating:real)
>   Table: WorksIn - (**nid:int**, **hid:int**, hours:real)
>  Table:
>   Hospital - (**hid:int**, hname:string, tid:int)
>  Table: Town -
>   (**tid:int**, tname:string, mayor:string)
>
> Explain what the following query retrieves:
>
> ```
> SELECT nname
> FROM Nurse N
> WHERE NOT EXISTS
>     (    (SELECT H.hid
>           FROM Hospital H
>           WHERE H.town = ‘Toronto’)
>      EXCEPT
>          (SELECT W.hid
>          FROM WorksIn W
>          WHERE N.nid = W.nid))
> ```

What does this query do? I can understand that the subquery returns all hospitals in Toronto that doesn't have any nurse work in, but I don't know how that connects with the NOT EXIST part.

Comment: Nice question paper! :)

Comment: NOT EXISTS is an operator that returns false if the subquery it references has any rows in it, and true otherwise. So it will select all nurses for which that subquery returns 0 rows.

Comment: Please don't post questions that have most of the content in an image when it's not required for the question asked. It makes it impossible to copy/paste any of the content for testing, and is horrific for those visiting the site from mobile devices. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I see. I will convert it to text when I have time :)

Comment: Fair enough. Is it OK if I downvote it or vote to close it until you have time and then reverse or vote to reopen when you do? :-) If you have time to read the comments, you have time to [edit] the question.

Comment: @KenWhite: Excellent point to raise; but perhaps pedantic in this instance due to the small size of the code excerpt. OP has accepted your point, and can be expected to know better next time.

Comment: @Pieter: Note I *did not* downvote or vote to close. You did notice the `:-)`, right? I appreciate the lecture, though. <G>

Comment: @KenWhite: I am known for stating the obvious better than most. I did miss the ;-), so it presumably went in one eye and out the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider in stages:

```
The set of nurses where 
  there does not exist
    a hospital in Toronto where the nurse doesn't work.
```

By law of excluded middle this becomes

```
The set of nurses where
  the nurse works in all Toronto hospitals
```

Note these points raised in discussion with a commentator:

- The sub-query is evaluated separately for each nurse, not singly on the set of all nurses
- That is to say, each nurse such that the set of Toronto hospitals where the nurse doesn't work is the empty set. Meaning for each nurse, (s)he works in all Toronto hospitals.
- Read the subquery as: "The set of Toronto Hospitals Except (read as set difference or minus) hospitals where the nurse works."

Comment: I got a different interpretation (please see below). What am I missing here?

Comment: OK. I'm in agreement now. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For each individual nurse the sub-query takes **all hospitals in Toronto** and excludes **all hospitals where s/he works**. That leaves us with **Toronto hospitals where s/he does not work**. To satisfy `NOT EXIST` such list for this nurse needs to be **empty**.  So this nurse must work **in each and every every Toronto hospital**.

So the query returns **nurses that work in each and every Toronto hospital**.

Given the size of Toronto and number of its hospitals it's not humanely possible, but this is the answer nevertheless.

Comment: The sub-query is evaluated separately for each nurse, not singly on the set of all nurses.

Comment: That is to say, for each nurse, the set of Toronto hospitals where the nurse doesn't work is the empty set. Meaning for each nurse, (s)he works in all Toronto hospitals.

Comment: The set of Toronto Hospitals **Except** (read as set difference or minus) hospitals where the nurse works.

Comment: I was thinking of upvoting your answer as useful; until you deleted all your comment questions, that is. Your mistake is a very common one, especially amongst any who have not taken an advance logic course to accompany their SQL training.

Comment: If a nurse does not work in toronto hospitals, the subquey will return all the toronto hospitals.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens - I agree with your answer and changed mine.  Let me assure you that I did take formal logic as a part of my Applied Math curriculum long time ago.  And the only comment I deleted was the one that actually repeated yours.